# Azure Table Storage columns count

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

How to get columns count in Azure Table Storage table?

The problem is when I query data I only see columns where data is present. It means that I cannot see the whole list of columns right away.

Answer (score 3):

> How to get columns count in Azure Table Storage table?

Simple answer is you can't because Azure Table Storage is `Schema Less` thus there is no predefined schema for a table in there (unlike relational databases).

There's no concept of nullable fields (only exception is `String` data type where you can store an empty string or null value) in Azure Tables.

In order to find all columns (rather attributes) you will need to fetch all entities from a table and find unique attributes among all the entities returned.